# How to connect Anycast M2 Plus RK2928 using Intel WiDi to Windows 7 laptop

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, intel-graphics, miracast

I bought Anycast M2 Plus RK2928 for 2nd external monitor for my Dell Inspiron 17R. I have newest graphic drivers installed (manual way, Windows 7 blocks original Intel's drivers, so I had to update the driver thorough Device Manager).

I have installed newest Intel(R) WiDi Update Tool and Intel(R) WiDi Remote Setup.

When I switch the dongle to Miracast mode and run scan from Intel WiDi Windows 7 application I get Anycast-8ABF33 in the list of "wireless displays" with status "available".

After clicking "connect" I have to wait for a while until Anycast changes its message from "Waiting for connection" to "Connection in process", then nothing else happens, and Intel WiDi application shows an error: "There are no wireless displays detected".

After Anycast dongle turn-off->turn-on cycle the problem persists.

Is there any other software for Windows 7 to use Miracast protocol to connect to external display?

My laptop has compatible processor (i7 3610QM), chipset (HM77) and WiFi (Intel Centrino Wireless-N 2230) - AFAIK all these components support WiDi.

Comment: Try it again with your Windows Firewall disabled, and then come back and let us know the results.

Comment: I don't use windows firewall (it is disabled). Now I am scanning Anycast with Nmap to know its ports, maybe there's ssh entrance left...

Comment: Similar problem with Windows 10 na brand new laptop Acer Aspire v3 372. My Android phone connects without problems

Comment: I have Anycast, and onscreen  it tells me the IP address is 192.168.49.1 - but that doesn't come up when I simply tell my tablet to "Cast Screen" and pick the device by name.  My windows 8.1 machine already has a second monitor so does not do anything when I tell it to connect to a wireless monitor.  Win7 seems to not have any way to do it.  I was able to use Win8.1 to connect to .149.1 in Chrome and tell it to connect to my router, though I can't tell that it does anything special.  It recommends the Anycast Connect app, but I don't see that in the Google play store - must be for iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use widi driver 3.5.41.0. I have a miracast rk2928 and this is the only widi driver that works for me. You can get it from [Softpedia](http://drivers.softpedia.com/get/Other-DRIVERS-TOOLS/INTEL/Intel-Wireless-Display-Software-35410-for-Windows-7-Windows-8.shtml).

Comment: where I could download it? please leave file name or link or md5 of the installer